# FileNotFoundExeption, invalid path?

Tags: java

Hello I have got a problem, which took me already several hours,
but I am not able to solve it.
My Code :

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    FileTester ft = new FileTester();
    boolean flag = false;
    try {
        flag = ft.checkFile("configuration/config.txt");
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {

        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    if(!flag){
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "please edit configuration/config.txt to continue!");
        System.exit(0);
    }
UserInterface ui = new UserInterface();
ui.setVisible(true);
}




public class FileTester{

    public boolean checkFile(String file) throws FileNotFoundException{
        String zeile = null;
        String path = getDirectory();
        int j = 0;
        for(int i = 0; i < path.length(); i++){
            char c = path.charAt(i);
            if(c == '.'){
                j = i;
                break;
            }
        }
        path = path.substring(0, j-6);
        System.out.println(path);
        file = path + file;
        System.out.println(file);
        int i = 0;

            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
            try {
                while ((zeile = in.readLine()) != null) {
                    if(zeile.startsWith("#")){

                    }else{
                    i++;
                    System.out.println(zeile);
                    }
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                return false;
                            }
            try {
                in.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                System.exit(0);
            }

        if(i >= 1){
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
    String getDirectory(){

        try {
            return String.valueOf(MainClass.class.getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource().getLocation().toURI().getPath());
        } catch (URISyntaxException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
            return "false";
        }
    }
}
```

Into the same Folder as my smartC.jar File is a subfolder "configuration" and into it my "config.txt" file, wich i want to read.
I compiled my programm and run it both on Windows7 and Linux Ubuntu/Lubuntu but
everytime i run it, it prints the rigth path :

```
Windows: 
C:\...\Desktop\smartC\configuration\config.txt
```

But then throws an FileNotFoundExeption.

Has someone an good idea ?

Comment: Have you tried using the files complete path?

Comment: I can't tell about the problem, but your code says "configuration" folder, then you talk about a "configurations" folder (with a 's') and then in the absolute path it is "configuration" without the 's' again. With this kind of question, you should be more precise about this.

Comment: @Unda Sorry its only a writing mistake in this post, the folder is corectly named "configuration"

Comment: @Vitor Martins, yes of course

Answer (score 0):

I soved it myself, the mistake was the following:
My program trys to open config.txt, but the filename was "config.txt" .
As consequence the program trys to open "config.txt.txt" and thats stupid.